# Script to check and find modified files among 10M records

Tags: optimization, hash, md5

I have a lot of small (10KB - 1MB) files (about 10M) in many folders such structure:

```
 - LEVEL 1 
  - LEVEL 2
   - LEVEL 3
    - file 1;
    - file 2; 
    ...
```

(files are stored on USB3.0 1TB disk. Total files size about 700MB)

And database on same disk (Microsoft Access 2007) of file hashes:

```
 file 1 - hash 1;
 file 2 - hash 2;
 ....
```

Everyday I need to calculate hash of each file and get the list of changed file(s) (if such exist).

How to write a proper algorithm to minimize script work time? I guess there are a few bottle neck:

- Disk I/O - how optimize disk read?
- Database read problem - how Access work with 10M row tables?
- CPU - do I need to parallelize hash calculating?
- I prefer C#, but maybe I need another language?
- Is it more effective to calculate hash of dir instead a file?

Anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel - [md5deep/hashdeep](http://md5deep.sourceforge.net/) has existed for years and does exactly this. It is cross-platform and will run on Windows, and can be invoked as an external process from C#.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for this answer.